# Git commit not showing on Github webpage

Tags: git, github, git-commit, github-for-windows

I am newbie when using Github so I have a question.
I am using the Windows Github client. I forked one repo and added some changes.
These changes are not shown on the Github webpage.

For example, [here](https://github.com/amacar/NiceHashBot/commit/7e0c8c94de9c589c9a13cc013461bc04a0a9fc8c) is my commit.

[Here](https://github.com/amacar/NiceHashBot) is the repo.

But on GitHub I see that there are no new commits, last is from forked repo:
[image]

But if I download the ZIP from: https://github.com/amacar/NiceHashBot then there I can see changes that I committed before.
I am a little confused as to what is wrong.

Comment: Very strange. I thought it would be something simple. But I just cloned your repo locally and did a `git log --decorate` and I see that your commit is what `master`, `origin/master`, and `origin/HEAD` all point to. The previous commit is `8ab4c58 gitignore update` which is what the web interface is showing as the tip of `master`. Maybe there's just some sort of web hook that wasn't triggered by your push. Try creating another branch and push to that one to see if it shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is working now. I did another branch and right after doing this my commit showed up on Github webpage. Must be something similar to what @onlynone said.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your commit is not part of the main branch, just hanging around. Try to checkout directly your commit by its hash, create a new branch for it, and then merge it to master:

```
git checkout 7e0c8c94de9 # changes HEAD to directly this commit
git checkout -b my-change # creates a new branch for the HEAD
git checkout master
git merge my-change # merges the new branch into master
git push # pushes master to github
```

Comment: I am using Github Desktop, do you know maybe how to do it using GUI?

Comment: That commit is indeed part of `master` you can see by running: `git branch --contains 7e0c8c9`

Comment: Now it seems to be ok on github as well. So maybe some github glich.

Comment: Yes, must be some glitch, but I waited for approx. 45min before I opened this question.